# Post Photo To Facebook Page Via Console App C#

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using C# ( console app ) and facebook graph api.

What I want to do is; I created ***a facebook page*** and now,
I want to publish a photo to that "facebook page" feed wall.
https://www.facebook.com/business/products/pages

So I need ***page access token***. To get page access token, I need **user access token** like they said in document (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens);

> you can retrieve the **page access token** using a ***user access token*** with the required permissions.

So how can I retrive user access token? I can't see any way to get it because I can't popup web facebook login screen, because this is a console application.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#usertokens

**Facebook Application Way**
If I create a facebook application, and get application Id & application secret I can get ***app token***, I can't post photo with this app token to "/{page-id}/photos" because graph api is returning "you need an **user access token** to query this endpoint". So how can I post a photo to page from console application ?

Comment: You can't. You have to use Facebook login to get a user access token. But you only need to do it once if you get an extended Page access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bypass facebook login to get user access token and page access token. If your console application requires a single access token then you can generate a long lived page access token from [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

And then you can hit this endpoint with 'url' post key to post photo using the generated page access token from graph explorer:

[https://graph.facebook.com/{page id}/photos?message={your message}&access_token={page access token}](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bpage%20id%7D/photos?message=%7Byour%20message%7D&access_token=%7Bpage%20access%20token%7D)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I research and found this tutorial; https://medium.com/@Jenananthan/how-to-create-non-expiry-facebook-page-token-6505c642d0b1 . I will mark your post as an answer. But actually I asked how to do it in c#. This token take thing requires a lot of manual work (you can create tokens only online-using graph api). With C# it's so much harder.